# Is cassandra supported as Quartz Datasource?

Tags: cassandra, quartz-scheduler

I intend to use clustering/load balancing feature of quartz. Can I use cassandra as a data source (DB) to be used by quartz ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like cassandra is not supported as datastore for quartz. Came across the below question on quartz user forum

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/quartz-scheduler/jdbcjobstore/o1XI6aWFMfI

Comment: The Quartz data model is not hard and with new Cassandra 3.4 Custom SASI indexes you could probably create your own job store implementation quite easily.  The problem comes in how to manage jobs across the cluster of Schedulers.  You'd have to use a different type of distributed locking mechanism than a RDBMS, maybe ZooKeeper?